# T4 Template in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, t4

The Add Controller and Add View dialogs both perform code generation that use T4 templates behind the scenes.  
These templates can be modified to customize the generated code from these tools.  You can find the templates at the following location:

> [Visual Studio Install Directory]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates[CSharp |
>   VisualBasic]\Web\MVC\CodeTemplates\

Now I will add my own T4 template to an existing list of templates.
Copy list.tt and paste it.
Then i rename the new template to MyList.tt

then I go to my Controller And Add view And Check Drop-Down Of templates
I Can't Find My New template  ?

Comment: Visual Studio does a lot of caching. Have you tried closing and reopening it?

Comment: no change i closed it and open again but cannot find my new template :(

Comment: Which visual studio you are using ? 2015, 2017 ?

Comment: VS 2017...........